# PL/SQL UTL_HTTP request returns "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges" on OCI AutonomousDB

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-autonomous-db

I'm trying to do a REST/HTTP request from PL/SQL in OCI.

I am stumped when trying UTL_HTTP ( but successful using APEX_WEB_SERVICE package).

Has anyone had success using UTL_HTTP on OCI AutonomousDB?

```
BEGIN
    UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET('');
    http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request(UTL_URL.Escape([url]), 'GET');
    http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(http_request);
    UTL_HTTP.read_text(http_response, return_text);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (return_text);
END;
```

> Error report –   ORA-01031: insufficient privileges   ORA-06512: at
> "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 136   ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1410
> ORA-06512: at line 7
> 01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
> *Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
> the necessary privileges.
> *Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
> administrator to grant you the necessary privileges

I have setup ACL as follows so http privilege is granted:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
         host => '[domain]',
        lower_port => 443,
        upper_port => 443,
        ace =>  xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('http'),
                             principal_name => '[name]',
                             start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP,
                             principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
END;
/
```

Comment: from the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/appendix-database-pl-sql-packages-restrictions.html#GUID-829A7D07-1EA4-4F59-AA60-F780FABAFDEC) it must be https, so are you trying http or https?

Comment: Yes, it's a https - requiring SSL certificate. So I 'SET_Wallet' - expecting the Amazon root certificate to authenticate automatically from the cached certs?

Comment: ..as per [Oracle Wallet configuration cannot be altered. All arguments for SET_WALLET API are ignored.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/appendix-database-pl-sql-packages-restrictions.html#GUID-829A7D07-1EA4-4F59-AA60-F780FABAFDEC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

`privilege_list => xs$name_list('connect', 'resolve')`

Docs says:

> Security Model
> This package is an invoker's rights package and the invoking user will need the `connect` privilege granted in the access control list assigned to the remote network host to which he wants to connect, as well as the `use-client-certificates` or the `use-passwords` privilege to authenticate himself with the remote Web server using the credentials stored in an Oracle wallet.

You also need 'resolve' to resolve the domain name.

Answer (score 2):

UTL_HTTP is unsupported on OCI Autonomous DB -

> [Oracle Database Features That Are Not Supported](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/atpdg/experienced-database-users.html#GUID-6141A383-B7B2-44D7-9121-94BCEF33AE4A)

> The following Oracle Database features, options and packs are not supported in Autonomous Database.

> UTL_SMTP, UTL_HTTP, and UTL_TCP PL/SQL packages

---

Now I know..

Answer (score 0):

Saying "*UTL_HTTP is unsupported on OCI Autonomous DB*" is misleading. First of all, you should clarify what flavor of ADB you are using. The doc link you referenced is for Autonomous Database on Dedicated Exadata Infrastructure (ADB-D). Autonomous Database on **Shared** Exadata Infrastructure (ADB-S) supports UTL_HTTP as already mentioned in the [ADB-S doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/appendix-database-pl-sql-packages-restrictions.html#GUID-829A7D07-1EA4-4F59-AA60-F780FABAFDEC).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that 'ctuzla'. Indeed it IS available on Shared.